# ZF2: Validate collection field based on parent fieldset element

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, zend-framework2

I'm trying to validate a field inside a Collection.

The Collection refers to Company Areas and is tied to a Company Fieldset

The validation needs to check that the Area Name doesn't exists for that Company in the Database yet.

I'm trying to do this using a Callback validator within my collection element 'area_name', my problem is that the collection is aware only of its own context, that means all fields associated to the Area but not aware of the Company context, so i can't filter my validator by its Company parent.

Is there a way to access the parent context of a collection? or should i need to initialize my form passing the Company object to the Collection prior validating?

**EDIT**: I forgot to mention that i'm using Doctrine2 so i'm not sure if it is possible to use the Db_NoRecordExists Validator bundled with ZF2

Comment: Did u try to use DoctrineModule's built-in `ObjectExists` and `NoObjectExists` validators? https://github.com/doctrine/DoctrineModule/blob/master/docs/validator.md

Comment: I did, but it doesn't filter by the Company, i mean if a X Company already have a X_A Area, NoObjectExists for Y Company returns false as X_A is not filtered.

I don't know if this is how the validator works or am i missing something.

Answer (score 0):

This is an old question and you might have fixed this already, but I had a similar problem recently.

You can create a function in your area model/service: validateAreaCompanyRelation(area, company)and in your fieldset use the callback to use it:

**AreaService class:**
add a method to return true or false based on query limited by 1 row. 
in my case it was somthing like this:

```
public function validateAreaCompanyRelation($company, $area)
    {
        $result = false;
        $count  = $this->getRepository()
                ->createQueryBuilder('q')
                ->select('q')
                ->innerJoin('q.company', 'c')
                ->innerJoin('q.area','b')
                ->where('b.id = :area and c.company = :company')
                ->setParameter('area',$area)
                ->setParameter('company',$area)
                ->setMaxResults( 1 )
                ->getQuery()
                ->getArrayResult();     
        if(count($count) <>1){
            $result=true;
        }
       return $result;
    }
```

**Area Field set:**
inject AreaService to the field set (pass it to construct in factory)

```
class AreaFieldset extends Fieldset implements InputFilterProviderInterface
{

private $areaService;
public function __construct(areaServiceEntityService $areaService)
{

$this->areaService = $areaService;
}

public function init() 
{

$this->add(
    array(
    'name' => 'area',
    'filters' => array(),
    'validators' => array (
    array(
    'name' => 'Zend\Validator\Callback',
    'options' => array(
    'messages' => array(
        \Zend\Validator\Callback::INVALID_VALUE => 'Your custom error message',
),
    'callback' => array($this,'vlidateUniqueRelation'),
),
), 

)
)
);
array(
    'name' => 'company',
    'filters' => array(),
    'validators' => array (
    array(
    'name' => 'Zend\Validator\Callback',
    'options' => array(
    'messages' => array(
    \Zend\Validator\Callback::INVALID_VALUE =>  'Your custom error message',,
),
    'callback' => array($this,'vlidateUniqueRelation'),
    ),
), 

    )
)
);
}

public function vlidateUniqueRelation($value, $context)
{
    // $value =  value
    // $context['xxxx'] =  xxxxx value
    // Logic to validate goes here
    $context["company"]
    $context["area"]
return $this->AreaService->validateAreaCompanyRelation($context["company"], $context["Area"]);
}
```